# Laravel 5.1 Class Inventory\Http\Controllers\inventory does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

my laravel system are working in my computer. when i upload into company server the error appear..

```
     ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
     Class Inventory\Http\Controllers\inventory does not exist
```

Here's my code

Routes.php

```
     Route::get('/','inventory@index');
```

Controller...
 Inventory.php

```
      namespace Inventory\Http\Controllers;
      use Inventory\Http\Requests;
      use Inventory\Http\Controllers\Controller;
      use Illuminate\Http\Request;
      use Inventory\Model\Inventorys;

      class Inventory extends Controller
      {
        public function index(){
        $inventory = Inventorys::select('*')->orderBy('id')->get();
        return view('body.body_list')->with('inventory',$inventory);
        }
      }
```

Thanks in advance... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoloaded class names are case sensitive:

```
Route::get('/', 'Inventory@index');
//               ^
```